# Json.Parse is automatically changing values

Tags: json, extjs

I am using JSON.parse to convert the below JSON into a javascript object.

```
 {"codeDetails":[{"codeID":3,"codeName":[5,8,-1,1,2,3,9,4,6,7,10]},{"codeID":2,"codeName":[0]},{"codeID":4,"CodeName":[1,2]}],"userName":"YYY","userID":"XXX"}
```

When I do a parse, the first value for codeID is changing from 3 to 1.

```
codeDetails:Array[3]
0:Object
codeID:1 -- this is supposed to be 3.
codeName:
Array[11]
0:5
1:8
2:-1
3:1
4:2
5:3
6:9
7:4
8:6
9:7
10:10
length:11
```

The below is the code I am using to parse.

```
 var uText = response.responseText; -- the response from my Ajax call.
 var jsonConvertion = JSON.parse(uText);
 detailtext = JSON.parse(jsonConvertion);
```

I tried changing the values JSON is returning but the first value is always changing to 1. Is there an alternative for Json.Parse?

Comment: Are you sure that in `uText` codeID = 3 ? Because I can't reproduce and I don't see why it would fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue with `JSON.parse()` (tested on up-to-date Chrome and Firefox) and no need to look for an alternative.

```js
var json = "{\"codeDetails\":[{\"codeID\":3,\"codeName\":[5,8,-1,1,2,3,9,4,6,7,10]},{\"codeID\":2,\"codeName\":[0]},{\"codeID\":4,\"CodeName\":[1,2]}],\"userName\":\"YYY\",\"userID\":\"XXX\"}";
var object = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(object.codeDetails[0].codeID); // writes out 3
```

Comment: Yes, It should but its not.

Comment: Trust me, the issue is not with `JSON.parse()`, as demonstrated in the snippet I posted.

Comment: Yeah, looks like there is no issue with the JSON.parse(), I replaced *_detailtext_* variable with *_JSON.parse(jsonConvertion)_* and I am able to access the right values. Still confused why the variable won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why it would convert to 1 but this is definitely an error :

```
 var jsonConvertion = JSON.parse(uText);
 detailtext = JSON.parse(jsonConvertion);
```

The seconde JSON.parse() call will fail because you will be trying to parse an object.

Comment: var jsonConvertion = JSON.parse(uText);

Comment: var jsonConvertion = JSON.parse(uText);

Comment: var _jsonConvertion = JSON.parse(uText)_ gave me the same string as the JSON value my call was returning. So I tried converting it again.